# How to deploy a cron job cloud function after onWrite of any collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) following is the code of running a cron job

```
exports.cronJob = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```

But I want to run cron job when there is any change detected in the

```
exports.changeDetected = functions.firestore
  .document('/myTable/{myID}')
  .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
    const dataAfterWrite = snapshot.after.data();
    const myID = context.params.myID;
    /*I want to deploy a cron job cloud function from here with the name of myID. something like this:

  exports.{$`myID`} = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
 */      
    return true;
  });
```

Is it possible to do that in firebase cloud functions? Can we deploy a firebase cron job cloud function when any change in any collection is detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really feasible to have a function deploy another function dynamically.  I suggest instead creating a single function that runs periodically, and have it check to see what work should be done at the time it triggers.  That work could be described using documents in Firestore, so all you would have to do is query for those documents, and take action based on what you find.

Comment: so can we deploy a firebase crone job cloud function when a change in any collection is detected?

Comment: I'm saying it's not feasible.